# Excel Worksheet Function: How to refer to a dynamic column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Note: Trying without VBA

Let's say I have in C1 the word "Hello"

From another cell, lets say A1, I want to return C:C, because in the first row 1:1, contains the word "Hello"

In A1, I could put:

```
=MATCH("Hello",1:1,0)
```

And this would return 3, as it is in the third column. However, I need it in the format C:C

ADDRESS function can return a specific cell using the column number 3, but not the entire column.

Ultimately, I want to use a COUNTIF(dynamicWholeColumn,criteriaCell)

Any ideas anyone?
Cheers.

Comment: That's a circular reference - you're referring to 1:1 in A1.

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the output of ADDRESS using string functions, to turn `$C$1` into `$C:$C`. But if you're putting it into COUNTIF, you'd be better using OFFSET and the output from MATCH.

`=COUNTIF(OFFSET($A:$A,0,MATCH("Hello",1:1,0)-1),"Hello")`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function below it will give your the row letter.

```
=CHAR(<COLUMN NUMBER>+64)
```

Therefore if you use the below you will get your column letter, C.

```
=CHAR(MATCH("Hello",1:1,0)+64)
```

All you therefore need to do is to concatenate it with itself to get what you are looking for, C:C.

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(MATCH("Hello",1:1,0)+64),":",CHAR(MATCH("Hello",1:1,0)+64))
```